# Generating a list of random numbers in java

Tags: java, random

I generate a random number 0 or 1

`int randomColor = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0 : 1;`

I need to create 52 random numbers and 26 of them will be 0 and 26 are 1

Comment: That doesn't sound very random...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this: Create a `List` of 52 numbers. Fill it with 26 zeroes and 26 ones, and then use `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle them in a random order.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    numbers.add(0);
    numbers.add(1);
}

Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and just 3 lines of code for the whole thing:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) list.add(i % 2);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Voila!